# Print HTML object content in Adobe Flex

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I used HTML browser object in the Flex Air project, but there's a problem with printing in Flex HTML browser.

1. JavaScript print function does not work
2. Does not open download windows

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you need more? I can't help with printing since I did not done printing with html pages(and the printing code that I had in an application was a mess ) about the other issue with the save file post more information? Is there a specific page?Maybe you can grab the href of the file using some JS and DOM code and show your custom save dialog

Comment: I can't review your project or write the solution for you, you have to do the research and ask a good question that adresses one problem and that people can answer and point you in the right direction , also try #flex on freenode IRC

Comment: thanks
I need a way to print the contents html object in Adobe flex(Air Project)?
Unfortunately printjob output that was not interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I used is to change some JavaScript functions with my own, so when a save dialog did not worked I investigated and the thing is that in a normal browser a new tab/window was opening with the URL of the download file, so I changed the open function

```
function newOpen(url, name, features) {

}

window.open=new open;
```

The above code was injected in the HTML page and run when the scripts was loaded. 
You should be able to do it from AS3 as well, you get the window object like this

```
var window:*=myHTMLComponent.htmlLoader.window;
```

Then as above you change the open function with a `newOpen` function and implement in the new function the things you need.

About printing it seems that you will have to use the Flash printing and print the HTML component, I found [a tutorial for this](http://dryicons.com/blog/2008/04/26/multiple-page-printing-from-a-html-adobe-air-application/).
I think this printing of HTML is not recommended (it worked for me with graphs and other components, but it is a lot of work to get it to look right) so maybe saving the HTML to disk and then printing the file using a native browser or program will work better.